# Why do merged rasters in QGIS look 'patchy'?

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

Poor title for this question, but I can't think of a better way to explain it.

I have merged two rasters. I want the joins to be seamless, but there is an obvious line where they meet...

[image]

I've tried playing around with the histogram buttons, but don't seem to be able to make them any better. Any ideas how I should change the rasters before merging?

Comment: Is your raster a Panchromatic image or a multiband one? That kind of issues happened to me quite a few times with PCT rasters.

Comment: Hi @MoreauColin, it's a single band from some Sentinel 2 imagery. I was planning to merge all the bands individually and then do a land-cover classification of the .vrt.

Comment: You will need to perform atmospheric correction on the images before merging.

Comment: Hi @Vesanto, I've spent a few days playing around with these, trying DOS1 correction, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect. The resulting image is still patchy. If there are any other suggestions, they would be welcome!

Comment: DOS3 or DOS4, FLAASH, ATCOR, ACORN, 6S, all option for atmospheric correction. The more costly commercial packages also have seam stitching. Is this the same band? How did you decide that seam?

Comment: Yes, they are both from the same band. I think the problem is because the land cover changed so much between the two dates. They were captured two months apart, and large areas of the image have changed. I am limited to QGIS, but perhaps something like "ArcGIS Colour Matching" (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000sw000000.htm) might be what I need? Is there an equivalent in QGIS?